# Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404

Tags: vb.net

The below error prompt when I implemented the Google calendar:

> Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404

Code:

```
Dim service As New CalendarService("cal1")
Dim entry As EventEntry = New EventEntry()

entry.Title.Text = Title

entry.Content.Content = Desc

Dim eventLocation As Where = New Where()


eventLocation.ValueString = Location
entry.Locations.Add(eventLocation)

'Dim dtstartdatetime As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 3, 30, 0)
Dim dtstartdatetime As DateTime = StartTime
'Dim dtenddatetime As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 4, 30, 0)
Dim dtenddatetime As DateTime = EndTime
Dim eventTime As [When] = New [When](dtstartdatetime, dtenddatetime)
entry.Times.Add(eventTime)

If (UserName <> "" And UserName.Length > 0) Then
    service.setUserCredentials(UserName, Password )
End If

Dim uripath As String = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + UserName + "/private/full"

Dim postUri = New Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full")

postUri = New Uri(uripath)

Dim requestFactory As GDataGAuthRequestFactory = service.RequestFactory
requestFactory.CreateRequest(GDataRequestType.Insert, postUri)

Dim insertedEntry As AtomEntry = service.Insert(postUri, entry)
```

Comment: are you sure: `http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full` is the write adresse? check the doc: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: Thanks for your help Mederic.
The address (http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full) is for old version and it was shut down on 2014. 
https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2014/10/deprecated-google-calendar-apis-v1-v2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is an old version and the service was shut down on 2014. Please refer to below link
https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2014/10/deprecated-google-calendar-apis-v1-v2.html